# The "for" loop iteration in a string

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;

int main()  
{           
  string s("some string");

  for (decltype(s.size()) index = 0;
       index != s.size() && !isspace(s[index]);
       ++index)
  {
    s[index] = toupper(s[index]);
  }

  std::cout << s << std::endl;        
  return 0;
}
```

Can someone tell me how the `for` loop in the program helps in uppercasing the strings first word?

Answer (score 4):

It replaces the character in the string with the return value of `toupper` of that same character, which is obviously the uppercased character, `a` becomes `A` and so forth.

The loop will stop when it encounters a space because of `&& !isspace(s[index])` so it will only uppercase the first word in a sentence.